# Android - Create app with pure Java and no XML?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-manifest

I'm wondering if it is possible to create an Android app with only Java. No XML, no other things.

In Eclipse, when I create a new Android Project, the Manifest xml-file and the main layout xml-file is automatically generated. Can I delete those files and replace them by a Java-file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you cannot remove the manifest file, beause it's an essential part of the application. You can, however, do all layouting with Java instead of XML, thus restricting the usage of XML to a single file. Is there a specific reason why you want to avoid XML? Especially considering the definition of interationalized string constants etc. it's very useful.

Comment: Yes, I really don´t like XML :D It was a step forward to me, when we were able to create the DOM without HTML, and it will of course be a step forward when I am able to create layouts directly from Java. I think I can solve this language thing much better in Java rather than XML.

Comment: Well...layouting only with Java is possible, albeit not particularly pretty. XML is much better suited for structural representation than a programming language. There are some drawbacks to using XML for layouting though, especially concerning the lack of checks for correctness (wrongly typed functions in "click" attributes...eew). And I myself hate to mix XML and Java, which is why in general I prefer Java layouting for Android. However, I'm a big fan of the XML manifest. Easy to read, well structured and has a strict definition.

Comment: @VanCoding Yeah you can solve this.. you just need some data structure on file where you store your translated strings and some easy way to access them from your application. Now where have I heard some technology that does exactly that?

Comment: You´re right. XML is genious for visual structures and layouts. It´s bad for defining settings and other data. JSON would be much better for such things, since its structure is closer to the structure of a program. BUT, as genious XML for structures may be, I hate mixing things...

Comment: @Voo: XML is a bad format to define language strings. JSON is a much better fitting format for this. Even defining the strings in Java is much prettier than doing it with XML. You have to open and close every tag and the whole file gets much much bigger.

Comment: Let the editor do the additional work (code completion works for XML too) or even better just use tools that parse it nicely. About size_ What internationalization files are larger than a few kb where it'd matter? You could use json, but what's the advantage - it doesn't save much size (theoretically it can get larger even) or is noticeably faster to parse. You could do it, but since the whole framework exists for XML you basically reinvent the wheel for no real advantage and lots of additional code.

Comment: @Voo this might be a programmers preference, but I´m a coder and I like to code. And I like to read my code, too. But generated code is unreadable and ugly and frustrates me. There are things that allow me faster & nicer programming like auto indention, syntax highlighting, a nice refractoring tool or code completion, but I hate tools that hide the code from me and generate it for me. First, it might be faster, but in the end, you lose the overview over your/the tools code and modifying things takes much more time.. Especially when you must change anything with only an editor.

Comment: Hum the automatically generated XML files look just fine to me and why would I even manually edit them? And I claim that accessing something as `R.string.<>` or `@string/<>` after creating it with the GUI editor is MUCH less work, less confusing, less error prone and MUCH more maintainable than implementing the whole necessary code for this yourself. Using blackboxes is just a foundation for modern work - using Android you just use the kernel, the JVM, the JIT and all the intermediary frameworks already why draw an arbitrary line there?

Comment: I used snappii.com to make apps. It's really easy, the web service allows to make mobile apps in minutes, and without programming skills at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the layouts you have two options

1. Declare UI elements in XML. Android provides a straightforward XML vocabulary that corresponds to the View classes and subclasses, such as those for widgets and layouts.
2. Instantiate layout elements at runtime. Your application can create View and ViewGroup objects (and manipulate their properties) programmatically.

So for the first question - yes - you can delete xml layout files (if you must).

I think you cannot get rid of the manifest.xml..Quoting:

> Every application must have an AndroidManifest.xml file (with precisely that name) in its root directory.

Comment: Does anyone have a simple example of how to accomplish this? I see lots of people saying "yes, it's possible to avoid using XML layouts", but no one providing an example of doing so.

Comment: People prefer not to create the View objects by hand - that's why there are no/few examples. It's easier to describe what you want in XML and leave the generation of those classes for the Android platform - not to mention, that if they change those View classes in the SDK and keep the XML vocabulary the same - you will automatically use the new code. I would recommend to go with the flow on this one. Disclaimer: I have not seen Android SDK In 5 years.

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible to avoid XML? Yes, with the exception of the manifest and perhaps some theme declarations (I'm not sure if there are public Java equivalents for everything we can set up via themes).

Is it a good idea? Heavens, no.

The point behind the resource system is to allow Android to transparently hand you the proper resources needed by the device at the present moment, based on both permanent device characteristics (e.g., screen density) and transient device characteristics (e.g., portrait vs. landscape orientation).

To avoid the resources, you will have to go through a bunch of `if` statements to determine which hunk of Java code to run, detecting all these things by hand. This gets significantly more complicated once you take into account changes in Android itself, as new configuration changes and values get added, making it difficult for you to support everything you need to in a backwards-compatible way.

Along the way, you will lose all tool support (drag-and-drop GUI building, MOTODEV Studio's string resource assistants, etc.), outside of plain Java editing and debugging.

You seem to be placing your own personal technical inclinations ahead of all other considerations. If this is some small personal project, that may be a fine attitude. If you are creating code to be developed and/or maintained by others over time, though, you need to factor in the needs of those other developers, and they may be much more open to XML than are you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this video, just posted by the android team: http://www.parleys.com/#st=5&id=2191&sl=8

It's all about layouts and includes how to layout apps using Java, not XML. However, you are warned that the android team wants you to use XML...

Answer (score 2):

yes it's possible to make an app with java and no xml.
here's a simple example.
i use eclipse.
first i made my own my class called MyView, which extends View.

```
public class MyView extends View {

    Paint paint;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setTextSize(50);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, paint);
        canvas.drawText("hello", 0, 150, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 150, 100, 170, paint);
    }

}
```

in the activity, i create a MyView object called myView.
i get rid of `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
then i type `setContentView(myView);`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyView myView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // i delete this
        myView = new MyView(this);
        setContentView(myView);
    }
}
```

res\layout\activity_main.xml file can now be deleted.
res\layout folder can now be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create all layout files from code. But it's reccomended to use the layout XML files.

The `AndroidManifest.xml` can not be replaced by code, since the system relies on the data included in this file.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree Van Coding. If you have the proper programming language, you can write much more concise layout definitions than with AXML.
[A C# example how to replace AXML layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B67dB.jpg)

```
ViewGroup Layout(ViewGroup layout, IList<View> contents) {
    if (contents != null)
        foreach (View v in contents)
            layout.AddView(v);

    return layout;
}
```

Comment: `ViewGroup Layout(ViewGroup layout, IList<View> contents) {
            if (contents != null) foreach (View v in contents) layout.AddView(v);
            return layout;
        }'