# can I delete xml files ? android

Tags: java, android, xml

whenever I create an activity in android, XML files are automatically generated. Can I delete them if I do the layout programmatically in Java code ?

Comment: try it? I'm pretty sure you cant as when you dynamically create attributes you need to assign them to a certain xml file, you can have a blank template and then programmaticly insert elements into the xml file. But from what i know you need to have something as when intent is created it's usually binded to a view. correct me if im wrong anyone?

Comment: yes you can delete xml files, but you have to be careful and this is not recommended. But, You cannot get rid of manifest xml file. You can get more help in this previous question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037203/android-create-app-with-pure-java-and-no-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure... You can do it.

Look this, [Layouts](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

So, regarding it, we can create our .xml files and then add to our *Project*.